# Focus a NodeList element

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, nodelist

`NodeList` items do not have a `focus` method. However, I've seen a few articles written with literally `nodeList[index].focus()` which must be incorrect, right?

How do we focus the element from a NodeList?

```
let nodeList:NodeList = el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
...
nodeList[0].focus(); // Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'Node'
(nodeList[0] as HTMLElement).focus(); // doesn't work
```

Comment: Does `let nodeList: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = ...` work? (note: you could just not explicitly type the `nodeList and it should be inferred correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NodeList` is not an narrow enough type; you have to specify that it's a node list of `HTMLElement`s. You can do this with the `NodeListOf<HTMLElement>` type:

```js
let nodeList: NodeListOf<HTMLElement> = el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
nodeList[0].focus();
```

Note that you could alternatively let the compiler infer the correct type of `nodeList` and avoid having to explicitly type it:

```js
let nodeList = el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('a');
nodeList[0].focus();
```